# Twig sometimes breaks JavaScript or CSS

Tags: templating, craft3

Sometimes when your javascripts or stylesheets are formatted a certain way, twig seems to try and render those snippets (whom always include curly brackets in some way).

For example, if you end you're CSS stylesheet with something like this;

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    background-color: lightblue;
  }
}
```

(I can't remember the exact case off the top of my head, but I believe this is it)

The stylesheet won't render, as twig throws an exception giving you a 500 error. It seems to be that the curly brackets (two next to each other in the flow) gets interpreted as twig.

The same goes for JavaScript, where a concrete example is instafeed.js if you import and compile with Parcel or Webpack or the likes, there's a line of code in that library that makes the .js file throw a 500 error because twig interprets the file. Specifically this line;

```
pattern = /(?:\{{2})([\w\[\]\.]+)(?:\}{2})/;
```

Again the curly brackets breaks the loading of the .js file.

I actually haven't gotten around to simply loading the javascript and css though basic tags in the html, so it might be that the issue is only present when loading through `{% do view.registerCssFile(url) %}` or `{% do view.registerJsFile(url) %}`.

Any simple workaround for this (maybe just loading with html like `<script src="{{ path-to-file }}">`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't put your CSS and JS files in the `/templates` folder. Store them on the front-end in the `/web` folder.

If they're not in the templates folder, Twig won't try to parse them.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `{% verbatim %}CSS or JS code here{% endverbatim %}`. Twig won't process text inside the `verbatim` tags.

Comment: It's actually not inline css or js, but loading external files. Very strange, and I seem to recall having seen a post about it online. No solution though, so it might be an inherent problem in twig.